# Any options to provide Enum evolution backward compatibility in Avro?

Tags: java, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have an enum in Avro schema which is something like this -> [A, B, C].

I am trying to add new field to enum to make it look like -> [A, B, C, D].

Obviously, this change is not backward compatible, because clients with the old schema will crash on trying to deserialize events with the new value "D".

Are there any options to provide the backward compatibility in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avro schema : is adding an enum value to existing schema backward compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60567697/avro-schema-is-adding-an-enum-value-to-existing-schema-backward-compatible)

Comment: @Scott Not it does not. These are different questions.