# How to add an enum value to an AVRO schema in a FULL compatible way?

Tags: java, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have an enum in an AVRO schema like this :

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "MySchema",
    "namespace": "com.company",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "color",
            "type": {
                "type": "enum",
                "name": "Color",
                "symbols": [
                    "UNKNOWN",
                    "GREEN",
                    "RED"
                ]
            },
            "default": "UNKNOWN"
        }
    ]
}
```

When using FULL (which means BACKWARD and FORWARD) compatibility mode, how am I supposed to add a new symbol to the enum ? Is this impossible ?

I read [Avro schema : is adding an enum value to existing schema backward compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60567697/avro-schema-is-adding-an-enum-value-to-existing-schema-backward-compatible) but it doesn't help.

Whenever I try to add a new value to the symbols it fails the compatibility check in the schema registry even though I have a default value on the enum. After testing a bit it seems that adding a new value is BACKWARD compatible but not FORWARD compatible. However, due to the default value I set I expected it to be also FORWARD compatible. Indeed the old reader schema should be able to read a value written by the new schema and default to the "UNKNOWN" enum value when it doesn't know the new symbol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears there is currently a bug in AVRO which affects the versions 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.11.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2 and further until it is fixed.

The bug is in avro handling of enum default value.

According to the [documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Schema+Resolution) on the reader side with an old schema, we should be able to deserialize a payload containing an enum value that was generated by the writer side having the new schema. Since the value is unknown to the reader it should be deserialized as the default value.

> A default value for this enumeration, used during resolution when the reader encounters a symbol from the writer that isn't defined in the reader's schema

However thats not what happen and the deserializer on the reader side fails with the exception `org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: No match for C`.

I have reported the bug [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-3313), and a pushed a reproduction test [here](https://github.com/idkw/avro/commit/7d36203c137aa6a728d5b85b87969a3f743b45ee)

Hope it attracts some attention from the maintainers :)

Comment: The default value need to be added in the `type` definition, that's why it's not working in your example.

Comment: @JérémieBolduc The issue is that I'm using Java classes annotated with avro annotations to generate avro schemas. It does not seem to be possible to specifiy an enum's default value at the class level :/

Comment: That's unfortunate... Other technologies like [Avro IDL](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/idl.html) support it. Using the right plugins, it allows you to generate the avro schemas and the Java source code. The issue is probably more with your annotation processor and not really with avro itself.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the symbol level defaults to achieve this, (by moving `default` inside the `type` definition). Hope this helps

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "MySchema",
"namespace": "com.company",
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "color",
        "type": {
            "type": "enum",
            "name": "Color",
            "symbols": [
                "UNKNOWN",
                "GREEN",
                "RED"
            ],
           "default": "UNKNOWN"
        }
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I'm using Java classes annotated with avro annotations to generate avro schemas. It does not seem to be possible to specifiy an enum's default value at the class level

Answer (score 0):

Adding new symbol into an enum is not FULL compatible , not even FORWARD compatible.

see ==> https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/880

Comment: This issue is old (older than avro 1.9.0 in fact). Since avro 1.9.0 enum have default values, see https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.9.0/spec.html#Enums. "default: A default value for this enumeration, used during resolution when the reader encounters a symbol from the writer that isn't defined in the reader's schema (optional)". So this seems to me that there is a bug. Why am I denied adding a symbol to an enum which has a default value ? The spec explictely allows it and explain how to handle the unknown symbol on the consumer side.

Comment: you are right ! i didn't pay attention that was an old issue ! i agree it look like a bug , should maybe try to create an issue on gitlhub

Comment: I have created the issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-3313 with a test reproducing the error at https://github.com/idkw/avro/commit/7d36203c137aa6a728d5b85b87969a3f743b45ee